# Succinct Add Months Formula

Tags: formula

Trying to do one but the characters involved mean that further calculations are impacted.

Essentially, taking a date field, a months field, to get an end date field.

```
DATE(year(SCD__c)+ floor((month(TODAY()) + Con_Len__c )/12) + if(mod( month(SCD__c) + 

Con_Len__c , 12 ) = 0,-1,0),
if( mod( month(SCD__c) + Con_Len__c , 12 ) = 0, 12 , mod( month(SCD__c) + Con_Len__c , 12 )),
min(
day(SCD__c),
case(
if( mod( month(SCD__c) + Con_Len__c , 12 ) = 0, 12 , mod( month(SCD__c) + Con_Len__c , 12 )),
9,30,
4,30,
6,30,
11,30,
2,(if(mod(year(SCD__c), 4) = 0, 29, 28)),
31)))
```

This is the one I am using at the moment and it's just too huge.

I don't want to go down the path of Apex.

Answer (score 0):

Although not succinct

Here is the relevant part from the discussion [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008vsfIAA):

```
DATE ( 

/*YEAR*/ 
YEAR ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + MP_Number_Date__c - 1)/12), 

/*MONTH*/ 
CASE ( MOD ( MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c )+MP_Number_Date__c, 12 ),0,12,MOD ( MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c )+MP_Number_Date__c, 12 )), 

/*DAY*/ 
MIN ( DAY ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ), 
CASE ( MOD ( MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c )+MP_Number_Date__c,12 ) ,9,30,4,30,6,30,11,30,2, 

/* return max days for February dependent on if end date is leap year */ IF ( MOD ( YEAR ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + MP_Number_Date__c)/12) , 400 ) = 0 || ( MOD ( YEAR ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + MP_Number_Date__c)/12) , 4 ) = 0 && MOD ( YEAR ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( X01_MP_Start_Date__c ) + MP_Number_Date__c)/12) , 100 ) <> 0 
) 
, 29,28) 

,31 ) ) 
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that is similar to mine. The sad issue is that it breaks character limits if you then go on to reference it.
Got a feeling that I need to look at what I am trying to answer rather than trying to shoehorn this in.